# Removing or hiding slug/permalink from htaccess

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, slug

I have this slug that i want to hide for SEO matters.

My current slug is: homepage.com/company/companyname
All i want is to be: homepage.com/companyname

I tried lots for plugins and htaccess codes but nothing is working.
Does anyone have a simple solution?

Comment: Is this a page? Is it a child of "company"? Would it break your site if you just removed the parent?

Comment: The "company" is a taxonomy slug. I am using the plugin WP Job Manager.

Comment: Check out [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+taxonomy+slug), maybe give [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-taxonomy-base-slug/) a spin.

Comment: I've used that, but still nothing happens.